# Sqaure Payment Gateway Checkout API CORS Issue

Tags: square-connect

I tried to integrate Square Payment gateway in my application, but i'm getting following error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1fFb.png)

I've tested it through postman. It's working fine in postman.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to do the HTTP request from the frontend browser (JavaScript). Square doesn't allow that with one of the most important reasons being that anyone would be able to access your personal access token and thus have access to your account.

With that said, you need to create your HTTP request in a back-end service using something like PHP/Java/Ruby/Node.js, etc.